# Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory

Tags: c++, macos, boost, clang, exc-bad-access

My platform is Mac OS X 10.9.2, Xcode 5.1 (clang 5.1.0), and my program uses `MLPACK` library which uses `Boost`. The program ran correctly several days ago. Today I run it but encounter the following error:

`Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at address: 0x000000010009a220
0x00000001001f3e7b in boost::math::lanczos::lanczos17m64::lanczos_sum<long double> ()`

which points me to `Boost`. I checked the `Boost`, its version is 1.55.0.

Any suggestion? I don't use `Boost` directly.

EDIT:

I found when I run the program in `Release` mode, no error occurs, but in `Debug` mode, error shows up.

Comment: Is it possible that you're giving MLPACK an invalid pointer that it gives straight to boost?

Comment: @dreamlax I don't think so, because the program crashes at beginning and doesn't run to the place where `MLPACK` is called.

Comment: Most likely you've got bugs in your code: memory corruptions or race conditions.